# This question is about continuity and partial derivative of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $D= [-1,1]*[-1,1]$. If the function $f:D\to\mathbb R$ is defined by  $$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)^2, &\text{(x,y)$\neq$ (0,0)}\\
0, &\text{(x,y)=(0,0)}
\end{cases}$$
then

1. $f$ is continuous at $(0,0).
2. Both the first order partial derivatives of $f$ exist at $(0,0)$.
3. $\iint_{D}|f(x,y)|^{1/2}$ $dx dy$ is finite.
4. $\iint_{D} |f(x,y)|$ $dx dy$ is finite.

I am preparing for a competitive exam and I was solving the previous year's questions so I came to this one. To find whether the given function is continuous or not, I took two paths $(y=x$ and $y=x^2)$. Two different values were the result therefore the function was not continuous at $(0,0)$ and hence I think that partial derivatives would not exist. I could not find anything about 3rd and 4th options. Please guide.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, **source**, possible strategies, **your current progress**, why the question is interesting or important, etc. Otherwise your question will likely be downvoted and closed by the community.

Comment: Thanks!! I added some details.

Comment: Note that a function need not be continuous for its partial derivatives to exist. Continuity is only a prerequisite for the total derivative to exist, which is a much stronger condition than partial differentiability.

Comment: Thanks!! Can you give some more information about it and please explain the 3rd and 4th options also.